# The settings for this list have been recently changed. Refresh your browser before editing this list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-object-model

I have a C# application from which I am uploading documents to a SharePoint 2010 Document Library (with version history enabled). The line of code I am using to upload the document is the one below:

```
Web.Files.Add(destinationURL, documentFileStream, metaDataHashTable, trueBooleanToOverwriteChanges);
```

The problem is occurring when I am uploading a document while having the edit page form of another document opened in a browser. When I try to click the Save button, it displays the mentioned error (The settings for this list have been recently changed. Refresh your browser before editing this list.)

I have upgraded the Sharepoint Foundation with the HotFix mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536591) but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem I done using `EventFiringEnabled`.

If you don't have any event receiver on particular list/libraries then use this.

```
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

Web.Files.Add(destinationURL, documentFileStream, metaDataHashTable, trueBooleanToOverwriteChanges);

 this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

and if you have event receiver associated with list/libraries then use same before starting code and make it true in finally block